# Fitting Parameters to the Heat Equation

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, physics, parametric-functions, heat-equation

As part of my research, I have been trying to use a model of heat conduction through a 2D layer given an input steady-state Gaussian power profile and a heat loss term to the environment. All but one of the parameters in the system's PDE are known values, and what I am trying to do is solve for the other. My problem arises because with an arbitrary value for that parameter, I need to integrate the resulting temperature profile. As such, I've been trying to define my integral as a function of the variable, g. Below is latest attempt:

```
h := 0; (* Wm^-2K^-1 *)
\[Kappa] := 50; (* Wm^-1K^-1 *)
d := 716 * 10^-12; (* m *)
w := 71 * 10^-8; (* m *)

(* Define the boundaries and the boundary conditions *)
\[CapitalOmega] = Disk[{0,0},10*w]; (* Assumed to be sufficiently larger than the laser width *)
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], D] = DirichletCondition[\[CapitalTheta][x, y] == 0, True];

(* Define the heat equation as a function of the parameter that we're trying to solve for*)
heateqn[g_] := \[Kappa] * Inactive[Laplacian][\[CapitalTheta][x, y], {x, y}] - ((g + h)/ d) * \[CapitalTheta][x, y] + (1 / d) * Exp[-((x^2 + y^2) / w^2)]

(* Define the Gaussian profile of the laser beam *)
gaussianProfile[x_, y_] :=  (x^2 + y^2)^(1/2) * Exp[-((x^2 + y^2) / w^2)]

(* Integrate the solution over the Gaussian profile of the laser beam to find the numerator of Rcalc *)
Numeratorvalue[gfit_?NumericQ] := With[{glocal = gfit}, 
    soln = NDSolveValue[{heateqn[glocal] == 0, Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], D]}, \[CapitalTheta], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]];
    NIntegrate[gaussianProfile[x, y] * soln[x,y], {x, y} \[Element] DiscretizeRegion[\[CapitalOmega]]]]
```

When I try to run this code, though, I get an error that `gfit_?NumericQ` is a protected variable. I've tried defining soln as a helper function outside of the `With` command and also using ParametricNDSolveValue in and outside my definition of the NumeratorIntegral. However, everything I've tried gives me the same error. Has anyone encountered this issue before, and if so, do you have any recommendations for workarounds?

Comment: When I execute `Numeratorvalue[1]` after your code, I get `1.47911*10^-23` without any errors. Have you cleared your definitions to eliminate any older definitions left hanging around? For example, start with `Clear["Global\`*"]` before your code.

Comment: I hadn't cleared it! Rookie mistake. I appreciate you pointing it out. I'm new to Mathematica coding.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different workflow, that you may find useful:

We use the [HeatTransferPDEComponent](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeatTransferPDEComponent.html) to set up the PDE:

```
d = 716*10^-12; (*m*)
w = 71*10^-8; (*m*)
vars = {\[CapitalTheta][x, y], {x, y}};
pars = <|"ThermalConductivity" -> 50, 
   "HeatSource" -> -(-((g + h)/d)*\[CapitalTheta][x, y] + (1/d)*
        Exp[-((x^2 + y^2)/w^2)]), h -> 0|>;
op = HeatTransferPDEComponent[vars, pars];
```

Next, we generate a mesh, such that this does not need to happen twice. Once during the PDE solving and a second time during the integration.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega]];
```

Create a parametric function in `g`

```
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{op == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[\[CapitalTheta][x, y] == 0, 
     True]}, \[CapitalTheta], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, g];
```

You can use the parametric function `pfun` with an argument for `g` and this will then return you an interpolating function for that specific value of `g`.

```
pfun[1]
```

We can now write a function `fun` of argument `g`:

```
gaussianProfile[x_, y_] := (x^2 + y^2)^(1/2)*Exp[-((x^2 + y^2)/w^2)]
fun[g_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  gaussianProfile[x, y]*pfun[g][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
```

You'd then call this function so:

```
fun[1]
```

Hope this helps.